# Post as page Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, api, rest, facebook-graph-api

It is maybe a duplicated question, sorry if it is.

I want to post on a Facebook page that I own. I am using the graph API but I don't know how can I do this.

I have an APP, I'm using it for Facebook login.  But I don't know if I have to make another APP just for the extra permissions for publishing on my page because I don't want that the APP ask to extra permissions to the users that are using the Facebook's login in my page.

My goal is create posts to my Facebook page from my website.

Thanks for the help, and sorry for my bad English writing.

Comment: What permissions your app ask a user for is up to you – after all, you specify those permissions on your call of the login dialog. And to make post on your FB page _as_ the page, you will need to get a page access token – see documentation, it is all explained in there.